# Trailing slashes on sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I noticed that sails.js default configuration is set to respond both pages with and without trailing slashes:

```
http://www.domain.com/page  

http://www.domain.com/page/
```

According to [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html), this is not a recommended behavior in terms of SEO as search engines sees it as two different pages with duplicate content.

Is there a simple configuration on sails to serve 301 on one to the other?
(or do I have to use rewrite rules?)

Comment: *“This is not a recommended behavior in terms of SEO as Google sees it as two different pages with duplicate content.”* [citation needed]

Comment: Added a link to Google's blog

Comment: And you don’t have a `rel="canonical"` already?

Comment: No I don't. There is only one route defined for both links, so they refer to the same view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might make a little hook like this one:

```js
// api/hooks/trimming.js
module.exports = function(sails) {
  return {
    routes: {
      before: {
        // Register a "before" shadow route to handle redirects
        'all /*': function(req, res, next){
          if (req.url.substr(-1) === '/' && req.url.length > 1) {
            return res.status(301).redirect(req.url.slice(0, -1));
          }
          return next();
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

> *(originally posted [here](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails?at=58b1a33ade50490822140084))*

Answer (score 1):

Just use `/` in your `config/routes.js`. Like this

```
module.exports.routes = {
  'get /page/'               : 'AnyController.page',
}
```